# Exception propagation in java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, forkjoinpool

There are two snippets of code.

In the first one we create the CompletableFuture from the task which always throws some exception. Then we apply "exceptionally" method to this future, then "theAccept" method. We DO NOT assign new future returned by theAccept method to any variable. Then we invoke "join" on original future. What we see is that "exceptionally" method has been invoked as well as the "thenAccept". We see It because they printed appropriate lines in output. But the Exception has not been suppressed by "exceptionally" method. Suppress exception and provide us with some default value instead is exactly what we expected from "exceptionally" in this case.

In second snippet we do almost the same but assign new returned future to variable and invoke "join" on It. In this case as expected exception is suppressed.

From my point of view for the first part the consistent behavior is either not to suppress exception and not to invoke "exceptionally" and "thenAccept" or call exceptionally and suppress exception.

Why do we have something in between?

First snippet:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(TestClass::doSomethingForInteger);

        future.exceptionally(e -> {
                    System.out.println("Exceptionally");
                    return 42;
                })
                .thenAccept(r -> {
                    System.out.println("Accept");
                });

        future.join();
    }

    private static int doSomethingForInteger() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
    }
}
```

Second snippet:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(TestClass::doSomethingForInteger);

        CompletableFuture<Void> voidCompletableFuture = future.exceptionally(e -> {
            System.out.println("Exceptionally");
            return 42;
        })
                .thenAccept(r -> {
                    System.out.println("Accept");
                });

        voidCompletableFuture.join();
    }

    private static int doSomethingForInteger() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as “suppressing an exception”. When you invoke `exceptionally`, you are creating a new future, which will be completed with the result of the previous stage or the result of evaluating the function if the previous stage completed exceptionally. The previous stage, i.e. the future you’re invoking `exceptionally` on, is not affected.

This applies to *all* methods chaining a depend function or action. Each of these methods creates a new future, which will be completed as documented. None of them affects the existing future you’re invoking the method on.

Perhaps, it becomes much clearer with the following example:

```
CompletableFuture<String> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    return "a string";
});

CompletableFuture<Integer> f2 = f1.thenApply(s -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
    return s.length();
});

f2.thenAccept(i -> System.out.println("result of f2 = "+i));

String s = f1.join();
System.out.println("result of f1 = "+s);

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Here, it should be clear that the result of the dependent stage, an `Integer`, can’t supersede the result of the prerequisite stage, a `String`. These simply are two different futures with different results. And since calling `join()` on `f1` queries for the result of the first stage, it isn’t dependent on `f2` and hence, does not even wait for its completion. (That’s also the reason why the code waits for the end of all background activity at the end).

The usage of `exceptionally` is not different. It might be confusing that the next stage has the same type and even the same result in the non-exceptional case, but it doesn’t change the fact that there are two distinct stages.

```
static void report(String s, CompletableFuture<?> f) {
    f.whenComplete((i,t) -> {
        if(t != null) System.out.println(s+" completed exceptionally with "+t);
        else System.out.println(s+" completed with value "+i);
    });
}
```

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error for testing");
});
CompletableFuture<Integer> f2 = f1.exceptionally(t -> 42);

report("f1", f1);
report("f2", f2);

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

There seems to be a widespread mindset of the `CompletableFuture` chaining methods to be some kind of builder for a single future, which unfortunately is misleadingly wrong. Another pitfall is the following mistake:

```
CompletableFuture<?> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    System.out.println("initial stage");
    return "";
}).thenApply(s -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    System.out.println("second stage");
    return s;
}).thenApply(s -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    System.out.println("third stage");
    return s;
}).thenAccept(s -> {
    System.out.println("last stage");
});

f.cancel(true);
report("f", f);

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

As explained, each chained method creates a new stage, so keeping a reference to the stage returned by the last chained method, i.e. the last stage, is suitable to get the final result. But canceling this stage will only cancel that last stage and none of the prerequisite stages. Also, after cancellation, the last stage does not depend on the other stages anymore, as it is already completed by cancellation and capable of reporting this exceptional result while the other, now unrelated stages are still being evaluated in the background.

Comment: The question was a bit different. I absolutely understand that chaining is not a kind of builder for single future. But as you can see in the first snippet I'm not store the future that returns by chaining to any variable. And the future I am  joining on is not dependent on any other future. So why "exceptionally" is invoked anyway?

Comment: The action you chained to the future will try to complete the newly created future, whether you store a reference to it or not. How is that code supposed to know whether you stored a reference to the future or not?

Comment: Newly created future does depend on original future not opposite, right? And why the original future should try to complete the newly created future? Sorry maybe It is silly question but I want to understand

Comment: It does so, because you told it so. Calling `exceptionally` on the future is like registering a listener for its completion. The future does not care what the listener does, it’s not different to `thenRun` etc. To stay with this analogy, you can only opt out a listener by deregistering it, which requires a reference to the listener. If you don’t keep it, the listener will still run, without any ability to deregister it. Likewise, when you don’t keep a reference to the newly created future, you don’t have the ability to cancel it, so you lost the possibility to opt out.

Comment: So ok, "exceptionally" and any other such methods not only create and return new future object but also registers a listener to the object they are applied to. But if we had stored reference and had joint on It, the exception would not be propagated and we would get the stub provided by "exceptionally", right. This is what I wanted to understand. Thank you!!