# Completable future - complete method

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have a code:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> c1 = new CompletableFuture<Integer>()
        .thenApply((data) -> data * 2);
c1.thenAccept(System.out::println);

c1.complete(20);


CompletableFuture<Integer> c2 = new CompletableFuture<>();

c2.thenApply(data -> data * 2)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
c2.complete(20);
```

Output:

> 20 40

**Question:**

1. Why there is a difference in output between c1 and c2?
2. Why there is a need to repeat future type in c1 by calling:

> new CompletableFuture<**Integer**>()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the methods of `CompletableFuture` (e.g. `thenApply`, `thenAccept`, etc.) return a *new* `CompletableFuture` instance. This forms a sort of "chain" where each new stage is dependent on the stage it was created from—its parent stage. When a stage completes, normally or exceptionally, the result is pushed to all its dependent, *non-completed*<sup>*</sup> stages (the same stage can have multiple dependent stages).

---

<sup>* As you'll see below you can complete a stage even if its parent hasn't completed yet. If and when the parent stage completes the *completed* dependent stage(s) will not be invoked as it's already completed. The consequences of this are covered briefly in an [answer by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880333/exception-propagation-in-java-util-concurrent-completablefuture/54925432#54925432) to another question.</sup>

---

#### Question 1

In your first example you have the following:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> c1 = new CompletableFuture<Integer>()
        .thenApply((data) -> data * 2);
c1.thenAccept(System.out::println);
c1.complete(20);
```

Here `c1` is the stage resulting from `thenApply`, not `new CompletableFuture<Integer>()`. When you call `c1.complete(20)` you are *completing* the `thenApply` stage (normally) with the given value (`20`). The call to `complete` is equivalent to the `Function` transforming the previous stage's result and returning `20`. Now that `thenApply` is completed it pushes the value to `thenAccept` which results in `20` being printed to the console.

In your second example you have the following:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> c2 = new CompletableFuture<>();
c2.thenApply(data -> data * 2)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
c2.complete(20);
```

Here `c2` is the stage resulting from `new CompletableFuture<>()`, which is the parent of the `thenApply` stage. So now when you call `c2.complete(20)` you are completing the *root* stage which pushes the value to `thenApply`. The `Function` then transforms the value by multiplying it by `2` and pushing that result to `thenAccept`. This results in `40` being printed out to the console.

---

#### Question 2

The reason you must repeat `<Integer>` in your first example is because the compiler cannot infer the type of the first stage without it. The signature of `thenApply` is:

```
<U> CompletableFuture<U> thenApply(Function<? super T, ? extends U>)
```

The `T` is determined by the type of this `CompletableFuture` (the one the method is invoked on). The `U` is determined by the `Function` and, to an extent, the left hand side of a variable assignment where applicable. This means when you use the diamond operator (`<>`) you are effectively using the following:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> c = new CompletableFuture<Object>()
        .thenApply(data -> data * 2);

// same as...
CompletableFuture<Integer> c = new CompletableFuture<>()
        .thenApply(data -> data * 2);
```

Since all the compiler knows about the type of `data` is that it's an `Object` the multiplication is invalid; an `Object` cannot be multiplied by `2`. Note that the above would be valid if you simply changed the `Function` from `data -> data * 2` to `data -> 2` (but obviously those two functions aren't equivalent). This is because the left hand side of the assignment is related to the result of `thenApply`, not `new CompletableFuture<>()`.

When you explicitly specify `<Integer>` the compiler then knows that the input type (`T`) of the `thenApply` stage is `Integer`, which means it knows `data` is an `Integer`; an `Integer` *can* be multiplied by `2`.

Comment: The point that these methods return *new* futures seems to be one that needs to be propagated far more. I just wrote [an answer to a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925432/2711488) a few hours earlier. Regarding the type inference, the compiler may also use the function and the target type to determine `T`, e.g. when you wrote `thenApply((Integer data) -> data * 2)`, but that won’t change the type of the preceding `new CompletableFuture<>()` expression, which gets inferred on its own. So it would still infer `CompletableFuture<Object>` and complain about mismatching types.

Comment: @Slaw When I change C1 to this: `CompletableFuture<Integer> c1 = new CompletableFuture<Integer>()
                .thenApply((data) -> data * 2);
        c1.thenApply(d -> d * 4);
        c1.thenAccept(System.out::println);` If I understand correctly, there I have stage c1 from: `CompletableFuture<Integer>().thenApply((data) -> data * 2);` And next I complete this stage (by c1.complete(20)) and 20 should be push to depends stage `c1.thenApply(d -> d * 4);` so the result should be `80`, but it still `20` - why? -#edit, Because, There I have 3 stages? One parent and two childs?

Comment: @ThomasBanderas Yes, now `thenApply(d -> d * 2)` (stage "A") has two dependent stages: `thenAccept(System.out::println)` (stage "B") and `thenApply(d -> d * 4)` (stage "C"). When you complete stage "A" with `20` _both_ dependent stages, "B" and "C", will receive `20` as input. Stage "B" prints out that input and you see `20`. Stage "C" takes that input and applies the function to it, resulting in `80`, and stops (i.e. it's complete but there's no dependent stages). If you chained another stage to stage "C", say another `thenAccept(System.out::println)`, you'd see both `20` and `80` printed.